# AWS AppSync - "Certificate is Invalid" error message when trying to create custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-appsync

I am trying to create a custom domain in AWS AppSync and have followed the below steps,

- Created an [origin certificate](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca/) in Cloudflare.
- Imported the certificate in AWS Certificate Manager.

Trying to create a new custom domain with name `api.<domain-name>.com`, the ACM certificate is listed in the drop-down. But after selecting it and clicking on create, getting the error message - **Certificate is invalid**.

Not sure why it says so, as the certificate is already successfully imported in ACM.
Any help is much appreciated.

Here's a snapshot of the error,

[image: error-snapshot]

**Note** -

- All the AWS resources are in `us-east-1` region.
- I am able to create a custom domain for API Gateway using the same certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare Origin CA is not supported as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/http-cert-authorities.html

> At this time, self-signed certificates are not supported by HTTP resolvers when using HTTPS. AWS AppSync recognizes the following Certificate Authorities when resolving SSL/TLS certificates for HTTPS:

Comment: I have already **imported** the certificate into ACM and it has the status as `Issued`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a screenshot? or open the cert in a cert manager. I am suspecting there is something wrong with the certificate chain.

Comment: I am able to open the cert in cert manager. Moreover I am able to use that for registering custom domain for API Gateway. So I don't think there is any issue with the certificate.

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot

Comment: I think Cloudflare Origin CA is not supported as per 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/http-cert-authorities.html

> At this time, self-signed certificates are not supported by HTTP resolvers 
when using HTTPS. AWS AppSync recognizes the following Certificate Authorities when resolving SSL/TLS certificates for HTTPS:

Comment: Oh! Yes, this is the issue, AppSync doesn't recognize Cloudflare CA (which is very weird). Thanks a lot! Please update the answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have updated the answer instead of adding a new one, thank you @gowthz